# In Vite2, How to import an ESModule in tailwind.config.js

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, vite

Building a Vite2 app.

tried to import an `ESModule` in `tailwind.config.js`.
The Module was exported like:

```
export default xxx;
```

Then I imported the module in `tailwind.config.js` like:

```
const xx = require('./xx/xxx');
```

But I got an Error:

```
[plugin:vite:css] Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I got an answer from Vite Discord channel. This is the solution to convert postcss and tailwindcss config files to ESModule.

Do this, and you can use `import` in those config files.

tailwind.config.js

```
export default {
  purge: ['./*.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx,css}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
import tailwind from 'tailwindcss'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'
import tailwindConfig from './tailwind.config.js'

export default {
  plugins: [tailwind(tailwindConfig), autoprefixer],
}
```

vite.config.js I added `import postcss from './postcss.config.js'`  and

```
css: {
  postcss,
},
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW, can use `.mjs` extension for webpack: 
`await import('./postcss.config.mjs').then((m) => m.default)`

Comment: I wonder why the Tailwind Vue 3 and Vite official installation guide https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite doesn't mention these essential steps?

Comment: Indeed it seems to work even though Tailwind authors say it's not supported https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/8029#issuecomment-1086875656

Comment: It's not worked for me unfortunately, glad you got it fixed though.