# Referencing Tailwind config variables (CommonJS) on the client

Tags: javascript, webpack, tailwind-css

Tailwind's [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script) states that you can reference variables inside your Javascript code via the resolveScript plugin. So, for example, the code on the client would look something like this:

```
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig'
import tailwindConfig from './tailwind.config.js'

const fullConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig)

fullConfig.theme.width[4] // => '1rem'
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66402879/in-vite2-how-to-import-an-esmodule-in-tailwind-config-js) explains how this can be done with Vite (I'm using Webpack). We're processing the Tailwind via the PostCSS Webpack loader, like this:

```
{
   loader: 'postcss-loader',
   options: {
      postcssOptions: {
        plugins: [
          require('tailwindcss')
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

This plugin requires that you provide the path to your Tailwind configuration file to import it on the client-side. Still, my tailwind configuration file lives outside my source folder for the client and is written in CommonJS syntax (e.g., I'm exporting it via `module.exports`). Therefore, attempts to import it as an EcmaScript module will not succeed (we are exporting our configuration using `module.exports` rather than `export default` in other words).

Does anyone know the fix for this? For example, is it possible to load a CommonJS tailwind file into the client, or would I have to convert the entirety of my build step process to ESM?

Comment: Didn't really get you about the ESM/CommonJS part. When requiring the config in a JavaScript file, it should be using the default js loader, which has nothing to do with postcss-loader. Are you able to get there by doing something like `require('tailwindcss/resolveConfig')(require('./tailwind.config.js'))`?

Comment: If you are trying to reference Tailwind CSS config values from Vite, here is an article explaining how: https://lobotuerto.com/notes/import-tailwind-config-in-vite